# Identifying waveform of oscillator under control of a pulley

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, waves, oscillators

Two objects of equal mass are connected as shown by a string over two smooth pulleys. $M2$ is initially rest on a table. $M1$ is initially pulled aside from the equilibrium position. The string is not slack.

[image]

$M1%$ is released. It completes $2$ oscillations before being caught again. Which graph shows this?

[image]

**The answer is C**

---

My working:

Firstly, getting the graphs figured out :

The zero position here would be equivalent to the centerline (or in this case, the bottom line) of the waveforms (as for some reason they only show what appears above the centerline).

[image]

[Source](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/waves/Lesson-0/Pendulum-Motion)

---

To make it easier to visualise, I would flip the pendulum to match the graph
[image]

---

**Step 1:**: As the pendulum is released, it goes from G to A i.e. from the bottom of the wave to the top.
[image]

**Step 2:**: The pendulum then goes from the top back to the bottom (i.e. the right back to the left if unrotated). SO on the waveform, from A back to G

[image]

**Step 3 and 4**: This process repeated again
[image]

---

**Combining the steps give:**

[image]

---

**Matching it to an answer option:**

There are 2 "humps" so I would choose B or D. As the pendulum is released from the far left (i.e. at position G), I would choose **D**, as the start of the graph should be at the G position.

**However, the answer is C. Why is this the case?**

Comment: Is there a conceptual question here? You appear only to be asking "Why isn't my answer correct? What am I doing wrong?" And your only difficulty seems to be interpreting the graphs, which are not labelled so it is uncertain what they are representing. (The question, as much as you have reproduced it, does not state what the graphs represent.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plots show the height of $M_2$ (NOT $M_1$) as a function of time. As $M_1$ accelerates it applies more tension to the rope, pulling $M_2$ into the air. $M_2$ is lifted into the air only when the tension in the rope is greater than the force of gravity on $M_2$, which means that $M_1$ needs a high enough velocity to induce enough tension to lift $M_2$. From this intuitive picture you can deduce what the height of $M_2$ should look like as a function of time.

I hope this is enough to get you started. Please ask if you need more direction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @alexvas. Ah, I see where I went wrong. One thing still confusing me is: "$M2$ is lifted into the air only when the tension in the rope is greater than the force of gravity on M2".

Force = mass * acceleration. When the ball is held at the left, acceleration is 0. When the ball is released, acceleration is **a**. How does acceleration change though? I know velocity changes, but doesn't acceleration remain constant? ...

Comment: So hence won't the tension force always be above or below the force of gravity on M2? I.e. whenever the ball is moving, won't it have a constant acceleration A. And whenever the ball is still/stopped (at each end on the left or right), acceleration will be 0.

With that in mind, I know there is a tension force 4 times during the 2 oscillations . 1) as the ball moves from left to right 2)when it moves from right to left 3) when it moves from left to right and 4) when it moves from right back to left again.

But how do I know if this acceleration is greater than gravity? And hence if ..

Comment: if the ball will move?

Comment: EDIT - sorry, I think I get it now. a=v^2/r, not a=gravity, as its centripetal acceleration. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Remember: the radial acceleration $a_c$ is dependent on the linear velocity $v$ by $a_c = \frac{v^2}{R}$. So as the velocity of $M_1$ increases, the tension in the rope will also increase.